# SQL server CASE select all but if value is a then other column value can not be NULL

Tags: sql, where-clause

Hi I need to select everything from column a but if value is 1 then the value in column b cannot be NULL. How do you write this in a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write this as:

```
where a <> 1 or b is not null
```

or equivalently:

```
where not (a = 1 and b is null)
```

Note:  These assume that `a` is not null.  To handle that, you can explicitly test for it:

```
where a <> 1 or a is null or b is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as:

where (a = 1 AND b is not null)